# RabbitMQ Exchange with catch all

Tags: routes, rabbitmq

in rabbitmq given

- an **exchange**
- two queue named **default** and **specific**
- two routing keys **all.specific** and **all.***

with the following scheme

[image]

I trying to implement the following (without success)

- if a message with routing key 'all.specific' arrives must be routed to **specific** queue
- if a message with routing key 'all.generic' arrives must be routed to the **default** queue

I tried two different approaces

1) exchange type 'direct'

I cannot use wildcards in the routing key so I cannot route 'all.generic', 'all.another_generic' and many other incoming messages

2) exchange type 'topic'

It routes 'all.generic', 'all.another_generic' to default queues, but 'all.specific' arrives to both queues why I want only specific queue to be reached.

I think that I'm using in the wrong way exchange and queues but I cannot understand how to implement this in the right, rabbitmq way.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best option for this won't be found in the bindings and routing keys.

i would look at Alternate Exchanges, instead.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html

With an AE, you can basically have a "catch all" exchange for any messages that does not match one of the bindings in the exchange where it was published.

in your case, your exchange would only have the `all.specific` binding to send messages to the `specific` queue.

the alternate exchange would deliver messages directly to the `generic` queue. this could be done with topics, to re-use the same routing key. or it could be done as a fanout exchange and only have the one queue bound to it.